# Large txt file reading via button waiting ages

Tags: java, android

**Hi, why this code working "onCreate" but don`t working in the button**

*Realy I use not more then 20Mb, but for testing I inserted 90Mb*

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   TextView textView;    DataInputStream textFileStream = null;
   public void readbigtext(){          
       try {
           textFileStream = new DataInputStream(getAssets().open(String.format("test1.txt")));
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(textFileStream);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {textView.append(sc.nextLine());}
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button bigbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bigbutton);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bigfile);
        textView.append("test begin");
        //90Mb here IS WORKING!           
        // readbigtext();
        bigbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //90Mb here DON`T WORKING
                readbigtext();
                }
        });
    }
    }
```

Comment: did you get an error message? did you check your logs? did you debug the code?

Comment: `textView.append(sc.nextLine())` - going to be a big textView

Comment: "don't working" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, describe what the exact observed behavior is and what the expected behavior should be. For UI issues, a screenshot or video is usually helpful. Include the exact wording of any error messages, including the full [stack trace](//stackoverflow.com/a/23353174) of any exceptions, if applicable, as well as which line of code the stack trace points to. Please see [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: No message, no logs : Only waiting, and after some seconds this message: 
 I/example.bigfil: Thread[3,tid=15898,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x7d54a16400,peer=0x174c00a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/example.bigfil: Wrote stack traces to '[tombstoned]'

Comment: @Zafar you should edit information into the question, not put it into comments where it's difficult to read

Comment: Also, dumping 90MB of text into a single TextView is just not going to end well.

Comment: But it works on protected void onCreate

Comment: Are you receive some kind of error?

Comment: @Zafar please don't post pictures of code, just the code

Comment: next i tryed for 14Mb , also don`t working, system is waiting or ask me close apk, strange  onCreate it working perfectly!

Comment: no errors, no logs, only ages of waiting )), how can I put here  long code?

Comment: @Zafar edit the question, and copy paste. Then format it as code.

Comment: Have you tried with `BufferedReader`? I use this inside my app to read `.txt` files and this works well. One difference is I read files from card, not from assets.

Comment: Solved, but it is horrible  : I created second activity and during onCreate loaded large file(16Mb) to the second layout, other ideas ?